# How can I have a python selenium webdriver script run 24/7?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, instagram

I'm new to programming, this being my first post, but I was wondering if there was a way to make selenium run while my computer is turned off? I made an instagram bot with selenium webdriver python but it only runs when I run it from my computer and turns off when I turn off my computer. I have seen post saying to host it in PythonAnywhere which I tried but selenium requires a webdriver (im using firefox so gekodriver). Is there a way of fixing this or is there another way of making an insagram bot without selenium webdriver?
Thank you

Comment: Why not use the APIs?

Comment: You are using the selenium webdriver, even when you are running it on your personal machine. You will need to use remote drivers to do this task, as, where your computer is turned off, there is no way it can connect to the internet and play around in instagram. However, you can provision a machine in google cloud platform, move your code there and keep it running, a very weak f1 micro instance should be enough and it can be running almost of free. This way, even when your machine is turned off, gcp will be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual machine and host a server and then through DevOps pipelines (Azure Pipelines/ Jenkins) can make your scripts run without manual intervention.